# No able to get the latest state of an object using provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am trying get the latest state of the name variable from the Home class, but I am getting a null instead of the value **Tenzin Nyidon**. I initialize the name variable inside the build method of the **MyHomePage** as you can see, and set the **notifyListeners()** method (*which notify all listeners*) inside the **onPress** of Navigate button.

**main.dart:**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<MyHomePage>(builder: (_) => MyHomePage(),)
      ],
          child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(

          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget with ChangeNotifier {

   String name; 

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //* Here I intialized the name variabel 
    name = "Tenzin Nyidon";
    return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(name),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Navigate"),
                  onPressed: (){
                    //* notify all listener
                    notifyListeners();
                    Navigator.of(context).push(

                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_){
                          return Home();
                        }
                      )

                    );                  
                    },
                )
              ],
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home.dart:**

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var provider = Provider.of<MyHomePage>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        //! I am getting a null value here
        child: Text("name from the main.dart: ${provider.name}"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to not create a provider with a stateless widget because it can't update its state.

and also you have to create a method to handle changes and then call changeNotifier();

such as:

```dart
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  String name;

  void changeName(String newValue){
     name = newValue;
   }
}
```

and then call in provider:

To change value:

```dart
Provider.of<MyProvider>(context).changeName(newValue);
```

To read it:

```dart
Provider.of<MyProvider>(context).name;
```

Comment: to change the name sure